# What are the automorphisme that permute roots of $X^3-1$? What is $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

**1)** What are the automorphisms that permute the roots of $X^3-1$ ?

Let denote $\alpha =e^{2i\pi/3}$. To me, there is $$id, (1\ \alpha ), \ (\alpha \ \alpha ^2),\ (1\ \alpha ^2), \ (1 \ \alpha\  \alpha ^2)\quad \text{and}\quad (1\ \alpha^2 \ \alpha),$$

and thus, if $K$ is the splitting field of $X^3-1$, then $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)\cong S_3$.

Is it correct ?

**2)** Why an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)\longrightarrow \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 2)$ can't send $i\longmapsto \sqrt 2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Gal$(K/\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. 
   Any element of $\mathbb{Q}$ must be fixed by any automorphism in the Galois group, so the "automorphisms" $$ (1 \>\alpha) (1 \>\alpha^2) (1 \>\alpha \>\alpha^2) (1 \>\alpha^2 \>\alpha)$$ cannot actually be automorphisms since they do not fix $1$. That leaves only two possible automorphisms left, so the Galois group cannot be larger than $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. It cannot be trivial since $K \neq \mathbb{Q}$, so the Galois group must be exactly $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
2. If $\phi$ is an automorphism and $x^2 + 1 = 0$, $\phi(x)^2 + 1 = 0$, so $\phi(x)$ can only be $i$ or $-i$. In general, automorphisms permute root sets of polynomials.

Comment: Perfect answer :-) Thank you. Therefore the only automorphisme is $(\alpha ,\alpha ^2)$.

Comment: Just a complement. If we would have 3 non rationnal roots $\alpha _1,\alpha _2,\alpha _3$ (of the same irreducible polynomial), the Galois group would be $(\alpha _1\alpha _2),(\alpha _2\alpha _3),(\alpha _1\alpha _3),(\alpha _1\alpha _2\alpha _3)$ and $(\alpha _1\alpha _3\alpha _2)$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily; if the discriminant of the polynomial is a perfect square the Galois group will only have even permutations as automorphisms (and the identity is always an automorphism). Many polynomials have "hidden" relations among the roots which take away more possible automorphisms, so it is so simple to determine the Galois group.

Comment: The reason the Galois group can be determined by the discriminant in the degree three irreducible case is a relatively straightforward argument.The discriminant is $(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2(\alpha_2-\alpha_3)^2(\alpha_3-\alpha_1)^2$  if this turns out to be a perfect square we have that $(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)(\alpha_2-\alpha_3)(\alpha_3-\alpha_1)\in\mathbb{Q}$ and is fixed by any automorphism.  However, odd permutations do not fix $(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)(\alpha_2-\alpha_3)(\alpha_3-\alpha_1)$ as an odd permutation introduce a negative.  Hence the Galois group must consist of even permutations.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The set of roots of any polynomial is fixed under an automorphism.  In this case, since the roots are $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, and $1$ each automorphism, $\varphi$, is determined by the image of $\alpha$.

That is $\varphi(\alpha^n)=[\varphi(\alpha)]^n$.

Since there are two possible images of $\alpha$ we have only two automorphisms and $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

**2)**  Since an automorphism must fix the set of roots of a polynomial we have that $\sqrt{2}$ must be sent to another root of $x^2-2$ and $i$ must be sent to another root of $x^2+1$.

Comment: Ok, but what are the automorphism in 1) ? For 2), they are the solution of $p(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2+1)$ which is a polynomial. Therefore $\sqrt 2$ could be send on $i$, no ?

Comment: Well in 1 there is the identity automorphism and the automorphism that permutes $\alpha$ and $\alpha^2$.  Here the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is the second cyclotomic polynomial which is $x^2+x+1$.

For 2 the root set of __every__ polynomial must be fixed.

Comment: Consider an automorphism $f$ which sends $\sqrt{2}$ to $i$. Then consider the equation $(\sqrt{2})^2-2=0$. Applying $f$ to both sides, we can $f(\sqrt{2})^2-2=0$. But if $f(\sqrt{2})$ equals $i$, then this means $i^2-2=0$, i.e. $-3=0$, which is not true.